# Field "X_Mutation" argument "type" requires type X, found X

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I use apollo clinet and react with graphql. When I try to mutate, it says types are not the same.
But they are the same.

Error:

```
Field "xMutation" argument "type" requires type X_value, found X_value.
```

```
    mutation Product (
        $id: String
        $type: milk
        $productId: String
    ) {
        productMutation (
            id: $id
            type: milk
            productId: $productId
        ) {
            ...productDetails
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing on

```
mutation Product (
    $id: String
    $type: milk
    $productId: String
) {
    productMutation (
        id: $id
        type: $type
        productId: $productId
    ) {
        ...productDetails
    }
}
```